# derivative of an integral which has a bound with multiple variables?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I want to find the derivative with respect to x of:

$$\int_0^{{\frac{x}{\sqrt4t}}} {e}^{-s^2}\,\mathrm{d}s$$

where t and x are both independent variables.
I thought you should use the fundamental theorem of calculus. However, since the upper bound of the integral is in terms of t and x, does this complicate the question?
Do I need to somehow use the chain rule to get it in terms of just x?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Leibiz integral rule to calculate the answer. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand how to use this... I can't seem to find anything about bounds with multiple variables?

Comment: Since $t$ and $x$ are independent variables, you can treat $t$ as an unknown constant (unless there is some explicitly specified relationship between them).